# 4x change in number of numpy array elements resulting in 32X increase in numpy file size

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array of shape (1684, 129, 522). Basically 1684 frames of dimensions 129X522 (only 1 channel so I have not specified it in the array.)

I was writing a function that would take 4 of these frames (each of 129 X 522) at a time and create a new input numpy array of size (4,129,522).

Hence, the net result would be a numpy array of shape (1684 X 4 X 129 X 522) from an original array shape of (1684 X 129 X 522)
Code below:

Function definition:

```
def create_frame_windows(episode, frame_window_length=4):
    episode_length, dim1, dim2=episode.shape
    new_episode=np.zeros((episode_length,frame_window_length,dim1, dim2))
    data_q_deque=deque(maxlen=4)
    for _ in range(frame_window_length):
        data_q_deque.append(np.zeros((dim1, dim2)))
    data_q=np.array(data_q_deque)
    print('Initial data queue',data_q.shape)
    for frame_no in range(len(episode)):
        frame=episode[frame_no]
        data_q[:-1]=data_q[1:]; data_q[-1]=frame
        new_episode[frame_no]=data_q
    print('New episode length',new_episode.shape)
    return new_episode
```

Run the function:

```
episode=np.load(os.path.join(paths.INPUT_DATA_PATH,epi_file))
print('Episode shape',episode.shape)
print('Initial size',sys.getsizeof(episode))
final_episode=create_frame_windows(episode,4)
print('Final episode shape',final_episode.shape)
print('Final size',sys.getsizeof(final_episode))
```

Code output:

```
Episode shape (1684, 129, 522)
Initial size 113397336
Final episode shape (1684, 4, 129, 522)
Final size 3628710304
```

My issue is that while the shape of the episodes are as expected, **the size of the final episode array is 32X the size of the original episode array** (3628710304 / 113397336 = 31.99). For just an increase of 4X increase in the number of elements of the array.

Have I written the function wrong or is there a more logical explanation for why this is happening? i.e. a 32X increase in numpy size (on disk) for a 4X increase in the number of elements

Comment: Is it possible the original array consisted of integers?  `np.zeros` by default creates floats, which are larger.

Comment: oh yes. since they were pixels, they were all integers.

Comment: You can pass a datatype to `np.zeros`.

Comment: Oh yes, Tim! The original frames were uint8. Made the changes to all dtypes as uint8 and it worked correctly. Is there any way, I can mark your comment as the correct one ? Thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that the original array consisted of integers.  `np.zeros` by default creates floats, which are larger.

You can pass a datatype to `np.zeros`.